# Get records from a specific month using SQLite

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, sqlite2

How would I write a SQLite query to select all records from a specific month?  My dates are stored as **Unix timestamps**.

PHP code is allowed in your solution if it's required. SQLite2-compatible queries only, please. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an efficient query then you should use BETWEEN:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE date BETWEEN $start AND $end
```

Where `start` and `end` are the unix timestamps for the start of the month and the end of the month. These can be calculated in PHP using [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and sent as parameters.

Comment: Well, it's not working, but I'll have to blame my script here, because the query (and my time-finding code) seems to be correct.

Comment: And it was my script. Fixed the bug in MY code and it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE DATETIME(your_unix_timestamp_col, 'unixepoch') BETWEEN YYYY-MM-DD 
                                                          AND YYYY-MM-DD
```

Replace the `YYYY-MM-DD` with the dates you desire.  See the reference page for other supported formats.

Reference:

- [SQLite - Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Answer (score 1):

Without calculating last day in month

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE strftime('%Y-%m',date(unix_timestamp,'unixepoch','localtime')) = '2010-03'
```

Comment: i want to select specific month record,  this script not work for me.